# Using jQuery flip plugin to flip a div on mouse hover

Tags: jquery

I am using the flip plugin of jquery. i need flip div on mouse over and on mouse out revert flip div. I would like to flip a card (div), and after it finished to flip, immediately revertFlip it. This is what I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.sponsorFlip').bind("click",function(){

    // $(this) point to the clicked .sponsorFlip element (caching it in elem for speed):

    var elem = $(this);

    // data('flipped') is a flag we set when we flip the element:

    if(elem.data('flipped'))
    {
        // If the element has already been flipped, use the revertFlip method
        // defined by the plug-in to revert to the default state automatically:

        elem.revertFlip();

        // Unsetting the flag:
        elem.data('flipped',false)
    }
    else
    {
        // Using the flip method defined by the plugin:

        elem.flip({
            direction:'lr',
            speed: 350,
            onBefore: function(){
                // Insert the contents of the .sponsorData div (hidden
                // from view with display:none) into the clicked
                // .sponsorFlip div before the flipping animation starts:

                elem.html(elem.siblings('.sponsorData').html());
            }
        });

        // Setting the flag:
        elem.data('flipped',true);
    }
});});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `onEnd` callback.

Like so:

```
elem.flip({
        direction:'lr',
        speed: 350,
        onBefore: function(){
            // Insert the contents of the .sponsorData div (hidden
            // from view with display:none) into the clicked
            // .sponsorFlip div before the flipping animation starts:

            elem.html(elem.siblings('.sponsorData').html());
        },
        onEnd: function() {
            elem.revertFlip();
        }
    });
```

See if that works for you.

Comment: no i need on hover change flip div and on mouse out revetflip

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, I've modified the code below to use the hover:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.sponsorFlip').hover(function(){

        // $(this) point to the clicked .sponsorFlip element (caching it in elem for speed):

        var elem = $(this);



            // Using the flip method defined by the plugin:

            elem.flip({
                direction:'lr',
                speed: 350,
                onBefore: function(){
                    // Insert the contents of the .sponsorData div (hidden
                    // from view with display:none) into the clicked
                    // .sponsorFlip div before the flipping animation starts:

                    elem.html(elem.siblings('.sponsorData').html());
                }

            });





    }, function() {$(this).revertFlip();});

});
```

Comment: elem isn't defined in the second function.